# javascript dropdown - on select go to url

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I'm using [ddSlick](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick) dropdown because it also has images. When you select a value nothing happens. How do I make it go to facebook.com or twitter.com if they are selected? Here is code:

```
var ddData = [
 {
 text: "Facebook",
 value: "FB",
 description: "Description with Facebook",
 imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png"
 },
 {
 text: "Twitter",
 value: "TWT",
 description: "Description with Twitter",
 imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/twitter-icon-32.png"
 }
 ];

$('#demoBasic').ddslick({
data: ddData,
width: 300,
imagePosition: "left",
selectText: "Select your favorite social network",
onSelected: function (data) {
console.log(data);
}
});
```

It uses these files: [jquery 1.7.2.](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js) and ddslick.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

kinda quick and dirty, but you can add additional attribute to the object that you pass:

```
var ddData = [
 {
     text: "Facebook",
     value: "FB",
     description: "Description with Facebook",
     imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png",
     url:"http://www.facebook.com"
 },
 {
     text: "Twitter",
     value: "TWT",
     description: "Description with Twitter",
     imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/twitter-icon-32.png",
     url:"http://www.twitter.com"
 }
 ];

$('#demoBasic').ddslick({
     data: ddData,
     width: 300,
     imagePosition: "left",
     selectText: "Select your favorite social network",
     onSelected: function (data) {
         window.location = data.selectedData.url;
}
});​
```